# Reduce number of lines in a switch / case with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, optimization

I created a piano, and I have a `case` for each key. There are 61 of them.

I have a switch case for the keydowns, and for the keyups. So 122 cases !

I show you an exemple for 3 keys :

```
switch (e.key) {
        // first row white keys
        case '&':
            document.getElementById("1").classList.add("active")
            if (audio1.paused) {
                audio1.play()
            } else {
                audio1.play()
                audio1.currentTime = 0
            }
            break;
        case 'é':
            document.getElementById("2").classList.add("active")
            if (audio2.paused) {
                audio2.play()
            } else {
                audio2.play()
                audio2.currentTime = 0
            }
            break;
        case '"':
            document.getElementById("3").classList.add("active")
            if (audio3.paused) {
                audio3.play()
            } else {
                audio3.play()
                audio3.currentTime = 0
            }
            break;
```

Here is the link if you want : [see the piano](https://brazillierjo.github.io/piano/)

Any idea how I can optimize this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a hash map of the keys to the player ids, something like this:

```
const elems = {
  '&': '1',
  'é': '2',
  '"': '3',
};

function toggleAudio(e) {
  const id = elems[e.key];
  const player = document.getElementById(id).classList.add('active');
  if (!player.paused) player.currentTime = 0
  player.play()
}
```